# ClojureScript - Cropper zoom on button click

Tags: clojurescript, cropperjs

I would like to zoom-in or zoom-out the image before cropping. I am using cropperjs. I am trying this by the following code.

```
(def Cropper (oget js/window "Cropper"))

(defn zoom-in [cropper-inst]
  (when cropper-inst
    (ocall cropper-inst "zoom" 0.1)))

(defn zoom-out [cropper-inst]
  (when cropper-inst
  (ocall cropper-inst "zoom" "-0.1")))

(defn mount-listeners [cropper]
  (let [zoom-in-el (ocall js/window "document.getElementById" "zoom-in-el")
          zoom-out-el (ocall js/window "document.getElementById" "zoom-out-el")
          cropper-el (-> cropper .-target)] 
      (ocall zoom-in-el "addEventListener" "click" (zoom-in cropper-el))))

(defn mount-cropper [wrap]
  (when wrap
    (when-let [image (oget wrap "firstChild")]
      (let [cropper (Cropper. image #js{:aspectRatio 1
                                        :viewMode 0
                                        :guides false
                                        :rotatable false
                                        :zoomable true
                                        :ready mount-listeners})]
        cropper))))
```

I mount the cropper on render. But, I cannot call the zoom method. It is showing an error saying **"Oops, Missing expected object key 'zoom'"**.

When I call the zoom as (ocall cropper-inst "cropper" "zoom" 0.1), the error message is **"Oops, Expected a function on key path 'cropper', got  instead"**.

The event object looks like the one in the below image:
[image]
But, crpper-el is a HTML tag as `<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg" class="spots_ui_components_cropper--cropped-image27970 spots_ui_components_cropper--cropped-image cropper-hidden">`
Any idea?

Comment: At the REPL, you could use `(js-keys cropper-inst)` to see the keys on that object.

Comment: @MikeFikes, I have edited the question to see the keys in the object. I am not sure why I am not getting the cropper element as an object as in the event.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it worked. I used **(.-cropper (js-this))** and added a **#** before the zoom-in method call.
Here is the correct code:

```
(def Cropper (oget js/window "Cropper"))

(defn zoom-in [cropper-inst]
  (when cropper-inst    
    (ocall cropper-inst "zoom" 0.1)))

(defn zoom-out [cropper-inst]
  (when cropper-inst
  (ocall cropper-inst "zoom" "-0.1")))

(defn mount-listeners [cropper]
  (let [zoom-in-el (ocall js/window "document.getElementById" "zoom-in-el")
          zoom-out-el (ocall js/window "document.getElementById" "zoom-out-el")
          cropper-this (.-cropper (js-this))]
      (ocall zoom-in-el "addEventListener" "click" #(zoom-in cropper-this))
      (ocall zoom-out-el "addEventListener" "click" #(zoom-out cropper-this))))

(defn mount-cropper [wrap]
  (when wrap
    (when-let [image (oget wrap "firstChild")]
      (let [cropper (Cropper. image #js{:aspectRatio 1
                                        :viewMode 0
                                        :guides false
                                        :rotatable false
                                        :zoomable true
                                        :ready mount-listeners})]
```